# how to read external files in electron with exe build

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I'm trying to read .pem certificate file from electron JS and when took exe build of that I'm getting the below error
[image]

I can read  that certificate file by running the application with npm run, it seems like I have to handle the path in some special way for electron. please help me on that.

please find my folder structure for your reference and i want read certificate file in the path app/qlik/certificates/

[image]